# How can I receive an input from my Terminal and use it properly

Tags: java, terminal

My task is to receive a command via the Terminal like "insert number" and call an insert methode using the number.

My methode is working.
This is my code snippet:

```
String command = Terminal.readLine();
    while (command != null) {

        switch (command) {
        case "insert number":
            String[] split = command.split(" ");
            linkedTuple.insert(Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
            break;
```

only a part of my complete code.
My problem is if I use case "insert number" it will only work if I really would write insert number in my terminal but instead I want to write for example insert 3 to insert the number 3 but how can I call that in my switch case?
My Terminal is working because a command like quit which is quitting my Application is working.

Thank you!

Edit: For clarity my main methode:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] tuple = { 1 };
    LinkedNaturalNumberTuple linkedTuple = new LinkedNaturalNumberTuple(
            tuple);


    String command = Terminal.readLine();
    String[] split = command.split(" ");
    while (command != null) {

        switch (split[0]) {
        case "insert":

            linkedTuple.insert(Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
            break;
        case "remove":

            Terminal.printLine(""
                    + linkedTuple.remove(Integer.parseInt(split[1])));
            break;
        case "swap":

            if (!linkedTuple.swap(Integer.parseInt(split[1]),
                    Integer.parseInt(split[2]))) {
                Terminal.printLine("Error, your numbers are invalid please try again!");
            }
            break;
        case "min":
            if (linkedTuple.min() == -1) {
                Terminal.printLine("Error, your tuple is empty, use insert number to insert a number!");
            } else {
                Terminal.printLine("" + linkedTuple.min());
            }
            break;
        case "max":
            if (linkedTuple.max() == -1) {
                Terminal.printLine("Error, your tuple is empty, use insert number to insert a number!");
            } else {
                Terminal.printLine("" + linkedTuple.max());
            }
            break;
        case "info":
            Terminal.printLine(linkedTuple.toString());
            break;
        case "quit":
            System.exit(1);
            break;

        }
        command = Terminal.readLine();
    }

}
```

If I enter a command and then want to enter another one the first one will be called instead.
for example:
info
then my tuple is printed
insert 3
my tuple is printed
quit
my tuple is printed 
etc

Comment: you wrote `String` inside a `switch()` and it doesn't give you error .? can you please confirm.?

Comment: no its not giving me an error lol

Comment: @Saif you can use string since jdk 7 in switch.

Comment: ohhh!!! they put it in `JDK 7`. Thanks to your question. yah i just googled it .. @almasshaikh and happy .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like:

```
String[] array = "insert number".split(" ");
....
switch (array[0]) {
case "insert":
```

In addition to above you need to swap the order of statement from

```
String command = Terminal.readLine();
String[] split = command.split(" ");
while (command != null) {
```

To

```
String command = Terminal.readLine();
String[] split;
while (command != null) {
    command = Terminal.readLine();
    split = command.split(" ");
```

So that you could loop in and ask for user input every time and take split from new command that user has entered.

Comment: Then I would rather use 
String[] array = command.split(" "); switch(array[0]){ case "insert":
because I also use remove number and stuff like that^^ thanks that should fix it

Comment: well but if I implement that and then run my application in eclipse and type in my terminal "info" (returning my current numbers array(standard: {1})) it is printing in 1 but if I know enter insert 3 it is still printing in a 1(like with my info command) if I now rerun it and start with insert 3 instead of info and then call info again it does nothing (Updated main thread)

Comment: paste you whole code post modification in the question please?

Comment: if I call command = Terminal.readLine(); at the beginning of my while loop I can delete it at the ending? am I right? I have to call it at the ending and not at the beginning of my while loop because If I call it at the beginning I have to double enter a command at the beginning (tested it right now)

Comment: No you need to ask user input every time isn't it so you get new command always?

Comment: yeah but I can't call it directly at the beginning of my while loop or I would have to write for the first time if I start my app for example: info and then again info the make my first command work after that it works but if I only write command = ... at the end it works perfectly

Comment: In that case, change you for loop to do while loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer after your edit:

At the end of your loop you do

```
command = Terminal.readLine();
```

But you don't split the new command. As a result, your switch statement still looks at the old split.

So you need to change the end of the loop to:

```
command = Terminal.readLine();
split = command.split(" ");
```

Comment: I can expect my commands to be: "command number" with only one space between(is told in my task)(updated main thread)

Comment: OK, then you can split by a single space if you want. I think giving flexibility is better, but you can always reduce the level of the code if you want to.

Comment: We are kinda restricted to what we are asked for :/ Not really allowed to "do more"

Comment: OK, this is all irrelevant because you now edited your question and your problem is completely different than what you wrote at first, so I'm going to change my answer.